# Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have this script which sends the source name and policy number to my Spring MVC controller.

```
$scope.doRepublish = function() {

    var republishSource = $scope.republishSource
    var republishPolicy = $scope.republishInput

    console.log(republishSource.name);
    console.log(republishPolicy);

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('republishSource', republishSource);
    data.append('republishInput', republishPolicy);
    var config = {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

    var url = "/republishPolicy"
    var rowCount = null;

    var responseMessage = null;

    $http.post(url, data, config)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.republishPolicy = response.data;
                if ($scope.republishPolicy.indexOf('Success') > -1) {
                    responseMessage = "success";
                } else {
                    responseMessage = "failure";
                }

                $("#republish_alert_" + responseMessage).show()
            });
};
```

I have checked in my console to see that, the source name and policy number are in the right format,

On processing this request to my controller, I get this exception:

> WARN 8168 --- [nio-8092-exec-7]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
>   Required String parameter 'republishSource' is not present

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/republishPolicy", produces = "application/json", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String republishPolicy(@RequestParam("republishSource") String sourceSystem,
            @RequestParam("republishInput") String policyNumber)
            throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        System.out.println(sourceSystem + " , " + policyNumber);
        return overrideProcessorDao.republishPolicy(sourceSystem, policyNumber);
    }
```

**Console Exception**:
[image: Console Exception]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is complaining because republishSource is null or not present.

The client is complaining because you are not capturing the error (you are missing the catch)

```
$http.post(url, data, config).then(function() {}).catch(function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

Comment: It is that, the controller fails to pick these values from javascript!

Comment: You have to check what is your data on the moment of posting. Do you need to post them with FormData? You can also send them as a plain json object

Comment: Yes A. Llorente. Got that !

Comment: If my answer is the correct answer please mark it so other people can benefit from it.